# Rails 3.0.9 Model attributes are lost on database query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, attributes

If i open the console and type in the following code, my model looses attributes. In all cases only the first attribute after the id is accessable. I had this problem on one server. My old server is working fine with the same code and same versions. Here the output:

```
irb(main):001:0> User.new 
=> #<User id: nil, encrypted_uid: nil, encrypted_access_token: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):002:0> User.first
=> #<User id: 1, encrypted_uid: "I7lPHOYoGMNWki3cZtb5oA==\n">

ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError (missing attribute: encrypted_access_token):
```

Has anyone an idea to get it working? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to recreate the application and copy the model into hte new application. after that everything worked fine. No clue what was wrong.